# Random translating nodes on expand/collapse

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been for days looking this problem, I think is something related to IDs, but I cannot found out what it is.

I made a jdfiddle to illustrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/32jrvjpr/8/

```
 var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function (d) {
            return d.data.idtermino;
        });
```

If you click on a child node, maybe at depth 3 you can notice it better. You can see that some nodes move and reallocate to the same position. Why is this happening?

I know there are some more things with bugs, but I change d3 version to v4 and there some behaviours that don't work anymore. I tried also to make zoom working.

Note: in this case, there are nodes that can be duplicated and they must appear once and two or more links must point to it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have two nodes with idtermino of 89961 - try renaming one ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32jrvjpr/9/))

Comment: Thank you for your comment Andrew. But I said that nodes can be duplicated (I didn't say how, that is with idtermino). Is there any possibility to archive this? I saw that without repetead ids it works properly. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to use duplicate keys - it modifies the exit selection:  If multiple elements have the same key, the duplicate elements are put into the exit selection (from [API docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data)). You could create a dummy key that isn't related to idtermino.

Comment: The thing is that if I do that, I can't have two parents pointing to the same child. I draw an example, if it clarifies my situation: https://imgur.com/a/j3AnN (see node wiith id=5). Thank you again for helping me :)